# Angular how to avoid loading many javascript files using ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Beginning angular developer here. I have a question on loading angular elements.
Suppose I am trying to create a SPA. I would configure some routes in route.js and then use ng-view in my layout template.

However, looking around online it seems many people are recommending organizing various angular elements (controllers, directives and services) as their own .js files in some kind of meaningful hierarchical folder system.

My question is: How do I avoid having to include all of these elements in my layout template's header. I mean, how do I avoid having many .js files included in my header for all the controllers, directives and services I user throughout my application?

Or is this just part of angular? That the layout template file has a whole bunch of included .js files?

Comment: Grunt is your friend. I use grunt to concatenate everything into one file. Grunt can also uglify it. Gulp does the same kind of stuff as well

Comment: I would say have a look at https://github.com/headjs/headjs . As their description says "the only script in your <head>"

Comment: I never trust anything that hasn't been updated for over a year. Grunt will change your life

Comment: @ribsies maybe put all files in one simple file works nice, but maybe I don't need to load so much lines of code if the user just stands on my login web page. So maybe the question is asking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to deal with this situation.  One of the more common is to use [Gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) or a similar Task Runner to [minify and concatenate](http://bitoftech.net/2014/05/05/angularjs-with-touch-of-gulpjs-tutorial/) your various script files into one distributable file.

You can also use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [ComponentJS](https://github.com/componentjs/component), or similar to define your components as modules to load on demand.

Mostly, this just comes down to how complex your application is, and how closely you want to micro-manage these optimizations.